# Sending individual email for each attachment in a Google Drive folder

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, email-attachments

I'm trying to write a script that will take all the files from a specific Google Drive folder and send them as email attachments. I need each attachment to be its own individual email.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID").getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  var attachments = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG));
    Logger.log(attachments)
  var emailAddress = "testest@test.com";
  var message = "image attached";
  var subject = "test";
  var attachment = (attachments)
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      attachments: attachments
    })
  }
}
```

At the minute, the script is sending the emails but adding attachments consecutively. So, if the folder has 3 JPEGs, it'll send 3 emails, one containing 1 attachment, another containing 2, and a 3rd containing all 3 attachments.

I'm really new to all this but really enjoying messing around with it. I'm confused as to what to do after getting the files and how I can then link them as attachments to their own individual email. Do I need to give each attachment its own array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**push** - adds file to stack.

**pop** - retrieve and remove file from stack.

With **push**, you simply add another file to your current list of files.

`attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG));*`

What you need to do is **pop** files from the list to remove them. So instead of grabbing the whole list like: 
`var attachment = (attachments)`

You should instead do:

`var attachment = attachments.pop()`

Currently your `while {...}` statement begins with adding another file to the list, then sending the whole list of files without removing the already sent file.

So your code should look like this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID").getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  var attachments = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG));
    Logger.log(attachments)
  var emailAddress = "testest@test.com";
  var message = "image attached";
  var subject = "test";
  var attachment = (attachments.pop())
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      attachments: attachments
    })
  }
}
```

Personally, I would remove the the list since you do not need to store each file, you just want to send them in separate mails.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID").getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    // gets curent file only
    var attachments = (file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG));
    Logger.log(attachments)
  var emailAddress = "testest@test.com";
  var message = "image attached";
  var subject = "test";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      attachments: attachments
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also move the unchanging `var` declarations outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's working perfectly. I really appreciate the help. 

I'm going to play around a little more to see if I can get it to delete the file from the drive once it's been sent.

Again, thanks for the help with this :)